# SQL query to find device list in specific AD group

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have AD Group which has user ID list but I need device list so looking for the SQL code which can convert this AD group and give me the list of device used by the users present in specific AD group.

Comment: This kind of data would usually be available if you are also using some kind of asset or configuration management tool.  If you do, refer to its reporting documentation, maybe there's a report already.